# UIImageView doesn't show UIImage gotten from notification

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsnotificationcenter

I'm developing a page view controller for showing PDF files and I want to start rendering a UIImage from a PDF page in a different thread and pass the rendered image to the main thread through notifications.

I started by creating a different method that renders my page in a UIImage and post a notification when the image is ready but at least for now I'm still doing it on the main thread.

```
- (void)generatePage:(int)pageNumber withSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIImage *resultingImage;

    CGFloat sizeRatio = size.width/size.height;

    CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = [self PDFDocumentRef];
    CGPDFPageRef myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef, pageNumber);

    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGFloat pdfHWRatio = pageRect.size.width/pageRect.size.height;

    CGFloat pdfScale;

    if (sizeRatio < pdfHWRatio) {
        pdfScale = size.width/pageRect.size.width;
    }
    else {
        pdfScale = size.height/pageRect.size.height;
    }
    pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*pdfScale, pageRect.size.height*pdfScale);
    pageRect.origin = CGPointZero;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, pdfScale, -pdfScale);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, myPageRef);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    if (resultingImage) {
        [pagesCache setObject:resultingImage
                   forKey:[self generateCacheNameWithSize:size
                                            andPageNumber:pageNumber]];
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                  resultingImage,
                                                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:pageNumber],
                                                                  nil]
                                                         forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                  CatalogRenderedPageImageKey,
                                                                  CatalogRenderedPageNumberKey,
                                                                  nil]];

        NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:CatalogRenderPageNotification
                                                         object:self
                                                       userInfo:userInfo];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];
    }


    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef);
}
```

I'm successfully getting the notification and the UIImage is correctly acquired (same object id) but the UIImageView is empty.

```
- (void) imageLoaded:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = note.userInfo;
    NSNumber *pageNumber = [userInfo objectForKey:CatalogRenderedPageNumberKey];

    if ([self.pageNumber isEqualToNumber:pageNumber]) {
        UIImage *image = [userInfo objectForKey:CatalogRenderedPageImageKey];
        self.image = image;
        self.imageView.image = _image;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:CatalogRenderPageNotification object:self.catalog];
    }
}
```

What am I missing? I've checked the storage property in the UIImageView and it's being filled with the UIImage.

You may have noticed that I'm saving my rendered images in a cache and truth is that when I get the images from that cache I'm able to see them in the UIImageView so I dismiss the chance that the UIImage is being generated badly.

---

UPDATE:
I started calling the generatePage in a different thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("renderingQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT), ^{
            [self generatePage:pageNumber withSize:size];
        });
```

And posting the notification in the main thread as @phyx23 suggested. It now works but I still don't understand why it didn't work before.

I'm leaving it open so that anyone can leave their thoughts on why this would happen.

Comment: What is `_image` in `self.imageView.image = _image;` ?

Comment: It's my ivar. It's from @synthesize image = _image;

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, the reason for the problem is that you are still in the image context when you assign the created image to the image view. You should end the image context with `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` first and then post the notification. 
Also when you start executing it in the background make sure you post the notification on the main thread.

```
resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef);

if (resultingImage) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [pagesCache setObject:resultingImage
               forKey:[self generateCacheNameWithSize:size
                                        andPageNumber:pageNumber]];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                              resultingImage,
                                                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:pageNumber],
                                                              nil]
                                                     forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                              CatalogRenderedPageImageKey,
                                                              CatalogRenderedPageNumberKey,
                                                              nil]];

    NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:CatalogRenderPageNotification
                                                     object:self
                                                   userInfo:userInfo];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];
  });
}
```

Comment: No, still the same thing. Thanks for the tip on the main thread. I was already aware that I need to do it but the way you did it is very clean.